# Input sanitation in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I know sql injections have been discussed many, many times here on stackoverflow.

What are the drawbacks on using this method

```
foreach($_POST as &$value)
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

It is only two lines, seems very convenient to use, but I think this is not a very much used approach.

And please, do not turn the discussion into prepared statements and PDO, even though it maybe should be considered best practice.

Comment: So, in the solution we propose we should avoid discussing the only real solution...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function to sanitize all data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705399/php-function-to-sanitize-all-data)

Comment: @fvu Why is prepared statements 'the only real solution'?

Comment: @Ragnar: because everything else is less robust.

Comment: @ragnar because due to the way it works it's the only one where you can be 100% sure no junk will pass through your sanitation.  Ever.  Prepared statements look a bit cumbersome at first, but you get used to the pretty quickly, and you'll ask yourself why you didn't switch earlier.

Comment: `$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST)` If you want to be short, at least be short. ;-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main drawback to using this code is the fact that you're modifying data in the POST array. This could impact operations on the POST array later on (like outputting to screen). It could also lead to confusion, if you're working with other programmers where they could reasonably expect the POST array to remain unchanged. For the previous reason, it could also make code maintenance more difficult. Anyone working on the code would need to know that you modified the POST array.

My suggestion, if you're set on using mysql_real_escape_string, instead of parameterized queries, is to make sure you use it in combination with sprintf and the correct type specifier, like so:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO purchases (amount, num_items, prod_descrip) 
                    VALUES (%f, %d, '%s')",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount'])
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num_items'])
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prod_descrip']));
```

Note that %f applies to float, %d to integer, and %s to string values. Also note that I'm directly using the $_POST data in the query string without any type of verification, which I wouldn't do in practice (just here for simplicity).

Answer (score 4):

Any data should be escaped not at the time it is collected, but at the time it is used, because you may use the same data in different context (MySQL query, preg pattern, HTML output) and each context needs different escaping. Moreover, if you escape the data in this way, what you are doing with other sources of data, lets say you are reading a value from a file or remote XML service? It is easy to forget to escape it, and it's easy to forget which value was escaped and which were not, either leaving your application vulnerable, or ending with double escaping. As @genesis φ pointed, the above method should be recursive to handle arrays as well. And you either need to use quotes around each value in the query, including numbers, or you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks in those parameters.

Comment: To avoid SQL injection, you don't need quotes around numbers when using mysql_real_eascape_string, if you use it in combination with sprintf and the appropriate type specifier (%d for int, %f for float).

Comment: That's correct, this is because it casts the variable to integer, it's the same as using (int) or intval(), but if all you do is to use mysql_real_escape_string without any casting, it won't protect you unless the value is in quotes. which may hurt performance, but that's another story

Answer (score 3):

This approach only makes sense if you want every single POST variable to be formatted appropriately for a MySQL query.

This is essentially identical to the theory behind Magic Quotes, which was deprecated for good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use this. There are cases you need only intval or you're passing POST array, which will fall into error here. You can simplify writing mysql_real_escape_string() everytime with your own function

```
function mres($what){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($what);
}
```

and using it

```
$query = '
    select column 
    from table 
    where column2 = "'.mres($_POST['var']).'"';
```

Comment: For what exactly do you need a separate function in this example? It's nothing more then an unnecessary wrapper… Also there is no such function as [`mysql_real_escaped_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to escape POST/GET data before the processing of it. Usually the data should be escaped when creating the query. For instance:

```
$query = '
    select column_name 
    from table_name 
    where column_name = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var_name']) .'"
';
```

Comment: @Ragnar123: because you can have an array in $_POST and it will fall into warning

Comment: @Ragnar123 Because when you escape the variable then its value is modified. This means that if you do some PHP logic before the query then the logic can fail. For instance: `if ($escaped_var == 'aaa"aaa')` will evaluate to false.

Comment: @genesis arrays are not the big problem because we can create a different initial code than the one in the question. We can just loop through arrays and escape the variables. The real problem is that escaped variables have modified values in the processing stage and this can led to unpredictable situations.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of efficiency, I would recommend something like this

```
$dbArr = array( 'key1','key2',...); //make these keys correspond with the POST vars you want in the db

foreach($dbArr as $goodCol){

    $sanitized[$goodCol] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$goodCol]);

}
```

Comment: But that will force you to revisit that spot of your code every time a parameter is added...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Agreed, and that can get quite cumbersome after the app has been in production for some time. Realistically prepared statements are the best route, but that was not the topic :P

Comment: @fvu "revisit that spot of your code" But if you add parameters, you'll need to edit the SQL-query anyway, so you are already revisiting that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you like regex and want explicit control of the input try this one.

```
function match_implode($filter,$val,$cut=255){
    $m=array();
    if(!is_string($val)){
        return false;
    }
    preg_match_all($filter,$val,$m);
    if(!empty($m[0])){
        return substr(implode($m[0]),0,$cut);
    }
    return false;
}
//Only Alpha-numeric with a max-length of 20 chars.
echo match_implode("{[A-Za-z0-9]}",$_POST["alpha"],20);

//Practical use
if($user_id=match_implode("{[0-9]}",$_POST["id"])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_login=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user_id=$user_id");
}

//If you need to parse and escape email :)
if($email=match_implode("{^[a-z0-9\å\ä\ö._-]+@[a-z0-9\å\ä\ö.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$}i",$_POST["email"])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_login=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE email='$email'");
}
```